# get options from configurable products in magento 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, configurable-product

on my productpage i've two options. The length and the width of an product who can manually typed in. in my cart.php i want to know the length and the width. how can i get these two values?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/bildschirmfoto20130521u.png/
(Länge in mm = length, Breite in mm = width)

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fetch as below

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');  
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true) as $option) {
    echo $option['value'] . ' ' . $option['label'] . "\n";
}
```

with attribute

for more understand please refer below [Link](http://www.atwix.com/magento/configurable-product-attributes/)

Comment: just pass as parameter instead of color to your attribute like length and width

Comment: $length = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'length');

Does not work... i think the option-field has another name than length. But i dont know the name of this field. how can i figure out the name? thank you!